# Can any Air rotameter be used for refrigerant gas by using equation conversion?

Tags: refrigeration, compressed-gases, compressible-flow

Currently, I am trying to find rotameter calibrated for R134A gas flow. However, most companies only sell rotameter or variable area flowmeter for water/Air/Nitrogen flow. Is it possible to use any air rotameter for R134A and convert the scale reading to corresponding refrigerant flow through the use of rotameter conversion equation(shown below) ? Will the converted mass flow rate be accurate?

Qs = Qi * sqrt((Ts*Pa)/(Ta*Ps))
Where Qs = true SCFM
Qi = indicated flowrate ('SCFM')
Ts = calibration temp (R)
Ta = actual temp (R)
Pa = actual pressure (psia)
Ps = calibration pressure (psia)
Thank you!